# Migrating my existing WP site to localhost

Tags: migration

I already have an existing WP site running, and am currently learning how to work on my site locally. I followed the tutorial at http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-install-wordpress-on-your-windows-computer-using-wamp/ and have WP installed locally now, works fine.

However this is the 'vanilla' WP installation; what I need is to migrate my entire site locally so I can work on the existing site locally. What would be the best way to go about it?

Comment: You will have to copy all files and database to local server.
Here is a nice tutorial for creating a local copy of your live website. Follow this guide. [How to Create a Local Copy of a Live WordPress Site](https://managewp.com/how-to-create-a-local-copy-of-a-live-wordpress-site)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the plugin [Duplicator](https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/).
This will copy all files and databases in one package, migrate the databases,...
You can even set up filters to exclude/include certain files.

It takes 4-5 minutes to migrate everything to localhost and vice-versa.

Comment: I've done it manually but will try this plugin next time, thanks. :)